# Graduated legend with intervals: Why does some points display another color

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have 6 point layers with an attribute that is a decimal number called sh value. I have to make a map for each layer displaying which interval the sh values belongs to.
I created a graduated legend with a grey scale based on the sh value attribute and manually decided the intervals. I have to make the legend the same for all 6 layers even though some point layers only have points in some of the intervals. It seem to work except for a one set of points (with same sh value) in each layer that display a yellow color in stead of the grey scale.

[image: Picture is a part of the map showing some of the points including the yellow ones]

Anyone that can help me figure that out?

Comment: it loos like, that this points are selected and will appear yellow then. Unselect all layers (button with two yellow squares and a red small square)